# Why is afterRender never called?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Have a look at the following sample HTML. It is a simple KO `foreach` binding and a button to add a new item to the `observableArray`. The addition works fine and the new item shows up. However, the `afterRender` method is never called - not after the initial binding and not after a new item is added (and rendered). Why?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CQNm6

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-bind="foreach: data.things, afterRender: afterRenderTest">
            <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
        </div>
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="data.things.push({ name: ko.observable('New Thing') });">Add New Thing</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Thing = (function ()
            {
                function Thing(p_name)
                {
                    this.name = ko.observable(p_name);
                }

                return Thing;
            })();
            var data =
            {
                things: ko.observableArray(
                [
                    new Thing("Thing One"),
                    new Thing("Thing Two"),
                    new Thing("Thing Three")
                ])
            };

            function afterRenderTest(elements)
            {
                alert("Rendered " + elements.length + " elements.");
            }

            ko.applyBindings();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong because `foreach`  binding either take an array or an object where you specify the additional events, arguments.

From the [documentaiton:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

> Pass the array that you wish to iterate over. The binding will output
>   a section of markup for each entry.
>
> Alternatively, pass a JavaScript object literal with a property called
>   `data` which is the array you wish to iterate over. The object literal
>   may also have other properties, such as `afterAdd` or `includeDestroyed`...

So you need write:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: data.things, afterRender: afterRenderTest }">
    <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uwJTu/)