# Knockout: afterRender not being called in a foreach template binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use Knockout's `afterRender` binding, but the function that I reference is never called.

I have nested view-models:
`vmConcepts` and `vmConcept`, where vmConcepts.Concepts = array of vmConcept objects.

`vmConcept` (the inner model) has a function `self.Rendered = function (elmnt) {...`

I bind vmConcepts (the outer model) to the following markup (you can see that this calls a nested template):

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'concept-template', foreach: { data: Concepts, afterRender: Rendered } } --><!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

My understanding is that this `afterRender` binding should be called for each vmConcept object (in vmConcepts.Concepts) passed to the `concept-template` template, but that doesn't happen. I've even added the same `Rendered` function to `vmConcepts` and that doesn't get hit either.

I've tried this as both a `data-bind` binding and as a virtual binding.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindings are messed up.  The *foreach* inside template isn't the same as the *foreach* binding.  The after rendered on the template will fire after every child.

Try this

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko template: { 
        name: 'concept-template', 
        foreach: Concepts, 
        afterRender: Rendered 
    } --><!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

I have a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4t94G/1/

Comment: Aha! I *did* previously have that syntax but changed it when I read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045740/why-is-afterrender-never-called, though as you pointed out, the `template` binding has a different `foreach`. I also had a problem with which view-model the referenced function is in, as I have a higher-level view-model which also has a property called `Concepts` and this is the view-model on which the afterRender function should sit.   Anyway, your answer is technically correct given my question, so you get the points.

Comment: Did this not answer your question though?  Were you able to get through your issue?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get through my issue, though it turned out that the problem wasn't in my binding attribute, it was due to the location (i.e., which view-model) of the afterRender function.